# ¿Por qué no me redondea los bordes en la imagen? Dart - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo el siguiente código y no me redondea los bordes de la imagen:

```
final imagen = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top:80.0,
        left: 20.0,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,  //PARA PROBAR CONTAINER
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
          boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(          //SOMBRA
            color: Color(0xffA4A4A4),
            offset: Offset(1.0, 5.0),
            blurRadius: 3.0,
          ),]

      ),

          child: Image.network(
            String_imagen,
            height: 220.0,
            width: 330.0,

            ),


      );
```

Foto de como me queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes revisar la respuesta para no dejar abierta esta pregunta ?

Answer (score 1):

Recién veo esta pregunta, es que no estaba con el tag de Flutter, la actualizaré.
De todas maneras voy a responder por si alguien busca la solución.

El problema es que el border solo lo aplica al `Container`, más no al child(`Image`), tienes varias opciones para solucionar esto, por ejemplo agregar un `ClipOval` widget al `Container` para cortarlo.

Pondré aquí la solución más sencilla, ya que estas usando `Container` y `BoxDecoration`, puedes aprovechar la propiedad `image` del `BoxDecoration`.

```
    Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 80.0,
                  left: 20.0,
                ),
                height: 220.0,
                width: 330.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.yellow, //PARA PROBAR CONTAINER
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                        "https://img.depor.com/files/ec_article_multimedia_gallery/uploads/2018/07/05/5b3e3ad01bd47.jpeg",
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      new BoxShadow(
                        //SOMBRA
                        color: Color(0xffA4A4A4),
                        offset: Offset(1.0, 5.0),
                        blurRadius: 3.0,
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

En estos casos, se puede envolver el child dentro del widget Image(), y setearle el fit, así tomará los parámetros del box decoration del container. Algo así por ejemplo:

```
child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/no-image.png'),
             isAntiAlias: true,
             fit: BoxFit.fill,
       ),
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes resolver esto envolviendo tu imagen con el widget ClipRRect, te dejo un fragmento del código que estoy desarrollando.

```
ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
                            ),
                            child: FadeInImage(
                              placeholder:
                                  AssetImage('assets/loading-gif2.gif'),

                              image: NetworkImage(
                                imgs[0],
                              ),
                              //height: 40,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          )
```